# Заменить один элемент списка на другой python

Tags: python, list

Хочу заменить введенное имя на уже существующее в списке. Почему-то не заменяется. В чем ошибка подскажите пожалуйста.

```
names = ['Сергей', 'Маша', 'Алена', 'Игорь']
n_name = input('Введите имя, которое хотите изменить: ')
if n_name in names:
    new_n_name = input('Введите имя, на которое хотите поменять: ')
    for n, i in enumerate(names):
        if i == new_n_name:
            names[n] = new_n_name

print('Новый список контактов выглядит так: \n{0}'.format(names))
```

Comment: Потому что у вас в условии прописано заменить тот элемент в списке, который совпадает с новым именем. Но, очевидно, нового имени в списке ещё нет, поэтому и сравнение никогда не срабатывает.

Comment: @andreymal я сделал `names.append(new_n_name)`, но не помогло. Можете показать как именно?

Comment: `if i == n_name` же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка здесь

```py
if i == new_n_name:
```

должно быть

```py
if i == n_name:
```

Хотя лучше сделать так

```py
if n_name in names:
    new_n_name = input('Введите имя, на которое хотите поменять: ')
    names = [name if name != n_name else new_n_name for name in names]
```

Или так

```py
if n_name in names:
    new_n_name = input('Введите имя, на которое хотите поменять: ')
    names = [*map({n_name: new_n_name}.get, names, names)]
```

Такой вариант подойдет и групповых замен.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, один элемент списка заменить другим можно через индекс:

```
names = ['Сергей', 'Маша', 'Алена', 'Игорь']
item = names.index(input('Введите имя, которое хотите изменить: '))
names[item] = input('Введите имя, на которое хотите поменять: ')
print('Новый список контактов выглядит так: \n{0}'.format(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names, n_name = ['Сергей', 'Маша', 'Алена', 'Игорь'], input('Введите имя, которое хотите изменить: ')
if n_name in names:
    names[names.index(n_name)] = input('Введите имя, на которое хотите поменять: ')
print('Новый список контактов выглядит так: \n{0}'.format(names))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]